# Http client returns what seems like encoded data

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am having an issue with my HTTP client.  The result I am getting as below:

"�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0Ԑ1k�0��@�á�;�4xk�bJ��A�**�\t�D��S'��p��{����+���\0\b�E\a�v�T݀��IJ�1D�,��YG5� �]8:�\t1�&衏�c�zú�LZ�\nzT8^�C�T����o/����M�ݴͱ��2w�Lo�J�4�L>ҢNɕ�W���\v��7.�����n�ct����L�0� fr�������j�(J\v/L1�A����\n\0\0��\0-�'�\0\0"

```
public HttpClient HttpClient
                {
                    get
                    {
                        
                    
                        if(_httpClient == null)
                        {
                            var serverUri = new Uri(_session.VipData.APIURL);
                            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverUri.Host) || serverUri.Port == 0)
                            {
                                throw new ConnectorServiceException("No session or session is not setup correctly");
                            }
                            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_session.Token))
                            {
                                throw new ConnectorServiceException("Invalid session token.");
                            }

                            //HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

                            Debug.WriteLine("Session tokken " + _session.Token);
                            var handler = CreateMonitoredClientHandler();

                            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpService.ServerCertificateCustomValidation;
                            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
                            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                            handler.UseCookies = true;
                            handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                            handler.CookieContainer.Add(serverUri, new Cookie("xxx", _session.Token));
                            
                            _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Base address " + serverUri);
                            _httpClient.BaseAddress = serverUri;
                            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                            //_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                            //_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json;charset=utf-8"));
                            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json") {  CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName });
                            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(_session.Token);
                            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
                            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
                        }
                        return _httpClient;
                    }
                }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong anymore. Below is how I call the

var result = await _session.HttpGetAsync("url", cancellationToken).GetResultAsync();

Comment: What processing are you doing to `result` once you get it?

Comment: It's probably the gzip'ed data, as requested by the request headers.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks you that fixed it